# Empty space is not getting trimmed CharConverter doesn't even called

Tags: java

Need to trim empty spaces across all model files, So wrote below CharConverter but not String is stored with empty spaces in db

// CharConverter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CharConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String value) {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        
         if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(value)){
            return null;
        }

        return value.trim();
    }

// model
  @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(NAME)
    @Convert(converter = CharConverter.class)
    private String name;
```

Comment: You know `trim()` only removes spaces from the beginning and end don't you?

Comment: So the problem is that values end up in the database untrimmed? `convertToDatabaseColumn` does nothing...

Comment: It doesn't trim spaces, The converter is not getting called

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Have you tried running your code in debug mode, to see if the `convertToEntityAttribute()` method is actually called?

Comment: Not sure but, it might be helpful if you added more details about the runtime environment.  What Java version are you using?  What DB are you using?  Is this in JPA or Hibernate?  Do you have any other `Converter`s that are working correctly?

Comment: @selvi how do you know it's not getting called?

Comment: // added trace and checked      log.trace("CharConverter.convertToEntityAttribute {} ", value);

Comment: openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14

Comment: @selvi as I mentioned before: `convertToEntityAttribute` is the method that is being called when loading data from the database. Check the other method which is called when converting from the java object to the database column value.